# How to share position of result of style.apply in DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How can i apply the result(location of dataframe, not the style itself) of styling my dataframe?

For example, i applied 'highlight_max' style to my data :

```
def highlight_max(data, color='red'):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series or DataFrame
    '''
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    #remove % and cast to float
    data = data.astype(float)
    if data.ndim == 1:  # Series from .apply(axis=0) or axis=1
        is_max = data == data.max()
        return [attr if v else '' for v in is_max]
    else:  # from .apply(axis=None)
        is_max = data == data.max().max()
        return pd.DataFrame(np.where(is_max, attr, ''),
                            index=data.index, columns=data.columns)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
aa = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [3,4], [1,9]])

aa.style.apply(highlight_max)
```

Out : [image]

And i want to keep location of highlighted cells and apply it to another dataframe like :

```
bb = pd.DataFrame([[7,3], [1,6], [4,2]])
bb.style.apply(**_Same_location_with_aa_**)
```

Out : [image]

Is there any style option to get this result? Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you can get the location by data.idxmax() just append it into a list and pass this list on 2nd df.

Comment: Thanks for answering Pygirl, i understood what you meant, but can't think out a way to apply it with style :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you cannot export the style formatting as it would apply the style to the max indices of the second dataframe. Instead you can do take a mask of the first dataframe which equals the max value and pass it under the function with `np.where`  like below:

```
def myf(x,color='red'):
    '''
    highlight based on the indices passed
    '''
    attr = 'background-color: {}'.format(color)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask,attr,''),index=x.index,columns=x.columns)
```

---

```
mask = aa.eq(aa.max())
display(aa.style.apply(myf,axis=None))
display(bb.style.apply(myf,axis=None))
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks anky it works! Declare 'mask' in definition as boolean array, and use it to df.style.apply for my second df. Simple! Just what i'm looking for :)